# Spring app Response to non-spring webapp

Tags: java, spring, http, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have two applications. One is a legacy webapp which is servlet-based. The other is a spring-based webapp. The legacy app has a page that has multiple jquery tabs. I want one of the tabs to act as an iframe to the spring based application. I have done the following to achieve that:

1. trigger an http post request (by openning and http url connection and writing to a printing to a writer) to the spring app, upon clicking on the tab name
2. the request contains information about the user in the legacy system, encrypted using a generated key shared on both systems
3. configure the spring mvc framework to intercept calls to the url and calls a method to process the request.

The request handling ideally should do the following:

1. decrypt the request data using the shared key
2. validate the request, license, etc
3. if the requester is deemed to be authentic and user has a valid license (uses an api for the license validation) then set up an account for the user and authenticate them programmatically into spring security
4. generate a random authentication key (to be used for future communications instead of the shared key)
5. send the random key back to legacy system (encrypted using the shared key)
6. direct the user to a specific page in the spring app

`1`,`2` and `3` are complete, but I am struggling with `4` and `5`. How can I send the second key to the legacy system and have the legacy system read it in using a `buffered reader` and then open the redirect page in the tab? Is it even possible in one response?

I used the `@ResponseBody` to return the key, but dont know how to send the redirect?
p.s. feel free to ask me questions if anything is not clear

Comment: As far as I can figure (if i understand what you are trying to do):- Within the spring controller use a service class to connect to your legacy app (you'll need to create a receiver) and send your auth key to that. If successful then return the correct page, if not redirect to an error page through the controller?

Comment: the request needs to the start from the legacy app. The spring app cannot connect to the legacy app, because it maybe hosted locally, where as the spring app is central. Which means the auth key needs to be sent in the body of the response.

Comment: Hmm ok I see. What if instead of an Iframe you used Ajax (perhaps jQuery ajax for ease of use) to contact the spring servlet, receive the data in response (the auth key) then if I recall the jquery ajax function has a success() method that is called on a successful ajax call.
You have the response body in the data element of the ajax method which can be referenced in the success function. You can then use the jQuery/JavaScript to decide what to do next.

Comment: I completely agree with you, and that's what I used first, but my supervisor had some concerns over cross server accessibility. This is for a product used on lots of computers with different configurations, and so the ajax route is not an option for that reason. I am thinking now to do it with two request-responses, first to authenticate and to create the random key, the second requests the page and uses the random key for authentication. It is probably not so bad :/

Comment: Good luck! Make sure you answer this question if you find a solution, i'd be interested to see it!

Comment: @Davos555, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it as follows:

1. the tab page on legacy application is preloaded with an iframe but without source, along with it a form with hidden fields is placed but without values, the form has the iframe as its target, and its action points to spring app url
2. when the tab page is opened, an ajax call is performed to a servlet on the legacy application
3. The servlet makes a call to the spring app on `/spring-url.do` with params. The call is performed by opening an `HttpURLConnection`.
4. `/spring-url.do` is intercepted by spring dispatcher and a method handles it as follows:
5. if it's the user's first time then generate a new key for them and write it to the response (it does so by forwarding the request to another controller whose return type is `@ResponseBody String`)
6. the response is read by the legacy application servlet and the key is persisted on the legacy app database for future communications
7. the servlet encrypts the user data using the new key and returns it to the ajax call
8. ajax success function reads the response and sets the value of the hidden form fields and programmatically submits the form
9. spring intercepts the url again, but this time it's an existing user, so it doesnot generate the new key, instead it validates the data and forwards request to a page on the spring app.